# ASPxGridView cell font

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to make only specified letter bold on my ASPxGridView. For example: only "Re" letters will be bold and the others are normal on the whole grid view cells.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this task by handling the [ASPxGridView.CustomColumnDisplayText](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic) event.

I have found a solution in the DX knowledge base:

http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q337393

http://www.devexpress.com/example=E2408